# Get a list of validation rules in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I need to get a list of validation rules out of a Model in my Rails application. I have searched around and looked through the source of a few client-side validation gems, but am still scratching my head about how to do this. Is there an easy way to just pull a list of validation rules out of a Rails model?

My specific use case is creating an API where the entry form for new items will be auto-generated from the Model definition, and I need to be able to express which fields are required, max length, etc. I already have fields, types, and length from the `columns` method, but there does not seem to be any type of similar `validations` method that returns what I need (mainly, required fields as enforced with `validates` and `validates_presence_of`, etc.).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check out the `#validators` and `#validators_on` methods:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html

You will have to write some custom code that operates on the returned objects and determines which attributes are required, i.e. which ones have `validates_presence_of`.

Comment: Seems to be what I need. Odd how this never came up while Googling - seems simple enough.